# Dudas del funcionamiento de las Alarmas y cómo debo guardarlas (Tener más de una activa)

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sharedpreferences

Tengo el código configurado que las *Alarmas* funcionen en formato **dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm** escribiéndolo en un `EditText` pero solamente funciona la última **Alarma** que activo, las demás quedan como si nada.

Mi duda es, por qué? Debo guardarlas en mi **SQLite**? Debo guardarlas en **SharedPreferences**, hay otra opción? O cuál de ellas es la mejor y cómo debería hacerlo?
Me gustaría poder añadir todas las **Alarmas** que quiera y que todas estén activas cuando llegue la fecha y la hora.
Yo tengo guardada la *fecha/hora* en mi **SQLite** pero como un *texto*, es decir, igual que me guarda los nombres me está guardando las **fechas/horas**, no sé si ese puede ser el problema.

EDITO: @dan_flo10

```
private void setAlarm(Uri passuri, int id) throws ParseException {

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
    java.util.Calendar cal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(sdf.parse(editTextFecha.getText().toString()));
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), pruebaintento.dos.notif.AlarmReceiver.class);
    //los extras
    intent.putExtra("titulo", editTextNombre.getText().toString());
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            getBaseContext(),
            id,
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

}
```

--

> setAlarm(uriAlarm, id);

Comment: `AlarmManger` y sobre todo `Intent` me hacen pensar que estás trabajando con Android. ¿Es correcto? Deberías añadir el tag de `android` si es así, porque si no la gente pensará que preguntas sobre Java SE.

Comment: Gracias @SJuan76 se me pasó por alto, añadido !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es necesario que guardes las alarmas si no lo deseas.

La razón por la que sólo te guarda la última es por dos cosas;

1. `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` con esa bandera le dices que cancele el anterior. Lo cual está bien en el caso que estés editando la misma alarma.
2. Tu variable `RQS_1` el "requestCode" es el mismo, para que que tengas varias alarmas crea una variable que se autoincremente. De preferencia que sea el `id` de un registro en la base de datos.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @dan_flo10 he actualizado el primer comentario añadiendo más información sobre mi código, he cambiado lo que me comentas por  FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT (no se si es el que debo poner, supongo que no porque sigue sin solucionarse mi problema) y he cambiado el RQS_1 por el ID de mi base de datos, qué hago mal?Podrías hacerme un ejemplo? Gracias de nuevo!

Comment: Puedes agregar todas la líneas o sea, también los imports, ya que el id que usas en el `PendingIntent` estoy seguro que es `import static android.R.attr.id;` lo cual está mal, mejor pasa el `id` como parámetro en `setAlarm(uriAlarm, id);` y define tu método así `private void setAlarm(Uri passuri, int id) throws ParseException {`

Comment: Acabo de añadir los import al primer comentario @dan_flo10

Comment: He editado de nuevo el primer comentario añadiendo la linea de código que he modificado con tus indicaciones por si ves algún error @dan_flo10

Comment: Efectivamente estas importando una constante. Pasa el `id` como parámetro cuando invocas `setAlarm(uriAlarm, id);` y ya

Comment: Muchas gracias @dan_flo10 solucionado! Ahora el problema es que puedo añadirlas pero no editarlas, dejé aquí la pregunta, si puedes pásate por si puedes ayudarme, gracias de nuevo! http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/44097/problemas-al-editar-alarma-se-a%C3%B1aden