# Problemas al Editar Alarma (Se añaden)

Tags: java, android

Cuando intento editar una Alarma para cambiarla de hora no se edita, se añade la nueva y sigue estando la anterior. Por ejemplo:

Tengo una Alarma el día 15/01/2017 19:00 y la edito para 15/01/2017 19:30 pues van a sonar las dos, por lo tanto no se edita sino que se añade.

EditarPersonaActivity

```
public class EditarPersonaActivity extends Activity {
    // Objetos.
    private Button butonLimpiar;
    private Button butonGuardar;
    private EditText editTextNombre;
    private EditText editTextFecha;
    private EditText editTextZodiaco;
    private DatabaseHandler baseDatos;
    private Bundle extras;
    private ImageView imagenPersona;
    private Mensaje mensaje;
    private int dia;
    private int mes;
    private int año;
    private static final int TIPO_DIALOGO = 0;
    private static DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener SelectorFecha;
    Uri uriAlarm;
    // Variables.
    private String ruta_imagen; // La ruta de la imagen que el usuario eligio
    // para la imagen de su persona.
    private int SELECCIONAR_IMAGEN = 237487;
    private int notification_id;
    // Constantes privadas.
    private static final int FECHA_DIALOGO_ID = 0;
    String[] zodiaco = {"Acuario (Ene. 20 - Feb. 18)", "Piscis (Feb. 19 - Marzo 20)", "Aries (Marzo 31 - Abril 19)", "Tauro (Abril 20 - Mayo 20)", "Géminis (Mayo 21 - Junio 20)", "Cáncer (Junio 21 - Julio 22)", "Leo (Julio 23 - Agosto 22)", "Virgo (Agosto 23 - Sep. 22)", "Libra (Sep. 23 - Oct. 22)", "Escorpio (Oct. 23 - Nov. 21)", "Sagitario (Nov. 22 - Dic. 21)", "Capricornio (Dic. 22 - Ene. 19)"};
    int flags[] = {R.drawable.icon_zod_acuario, R.drawable.icon_zod_piscis, R.drawable.icon_zod_aries, R.drawable.icon_zod_tauro, R.drawable.icon_zod_geminis, R.drawable.icon_zod_cancer, R.drawable.icon_zod_leo, R.drawable.icon_zod_virgo, R.drawable.icon_zod_libra, R.drawable.icon_zod_escorpio, R.drawable.icon_zod_sagitario, R.drawable.icon_zod_capricornio};

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.editar_persona);

        // Hace referencia a los objetos xml.
        butonGuardar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botonGuardar);
        butonLimpiar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botonLimpiar);
        editTextNombre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextNombre);
        editTextFecha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextFecha);
        editTextZodiaco = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextZodiaco);
        imagenPersona = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagenPersona);
        uriAlarm = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);

        Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();
        dia = calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        mes = calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        año = calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mostrarFecha();
        SelectorFecha = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                dia = dayOfMonth;
                mes = month;
                año = year;
                mostrarFecha();
            }
        };

    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case 0:
                return new DatePickerDialog(this, SelectorFecha, dia, mes, año);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void mostrarCalendario(View control) {
        showDialog(TIPO_DIALOGO);
    }


    public void mostrarFecha() {
        editTextFecha.setText(dia + "/" + (mes + 1) + "/" + año);

        // Se crea el objeto mensaje.
        mensaje = new Mensaje(getApplicationContext());

        // Recupera en un Objeto Bundle si tiene valores que fueron pasados como
        // parametro de una actividad.
        extras = getIntent().getExtras();


        if (estadoEditarPersona()) {
            editTextNombre.setText(extras.getString("nombre"));
            editTextFecha.setText(extras.getString("fecha"));
            editTextZodiaco.setText(extras.getString("zodiaco"));
            ruta_imagen = extras.getString("ruta_imagen");
        }

        // Agrega nuevo registro de una persona.
        butonGuardar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (verificarCampoNombre() && verificarCampoFecha()
                        && verificarCampoZodiaco()) {
                    if (estadoEditarPersona()) {
                        editarPersona();
                    } else {
                        try {
                            notification_id = (int) insertarNuevoPersona();
                            setAlarm(uriAlarm, notification_id);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                    // Finaliza la actividad EditarPersonaActivity.
                    finish();
                } else {
                    if (editTextNombre.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                        mensaje.mostrarMensajeCorto("Introduzca un Nombre");
                    }
                    if (editTextFecha.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                        mensaje.mostrarMensajeCorto("Introduzca una Fecha");
                    }
                    if (editTextZodiaco.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                        mensaje.mostrarMensajeCorto("Introduzca su Zodiaco");
                    }
                }
            }
        });


        // Limpia los campos.
        butonLimpiar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                limpiarCampos();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Metodo privado que limpia los campos.
     */
    private void limpiarCampos() {
        editTextNombre.setText("");
        editTextFecha.setText("");
        editTextZodiaco.setText("");
    }

    /**
     * Metodo privado que verifica que se cambio el valor de Nombre o no está en
     * blanco (vacio).
     */
    private boolean verificarCampoNombre() {
        if (editTextNombre.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Metodo privado que verifica que se cambio el valor de Fecha o no
     * está en blanco (vacio).
     */
    private boolean verificarCampoFecha() {
        if (editTextFecha.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Metodo privado que verifica que se cambio el valor de la Zodiaco o no está
     * en blanco (vacio).
     */
    private boolean verificarCampoZodiaco() {
        if (editTextZodiaco.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Metodo privado que insertar una nueva Persona.
     */
    private long insertarNuevoPersona() {
        long personaId = -1;
        baseDatos = new DatabaseHandler(EditarPersonaActivity.this);

        try {
            // Crear objeto Persona.
            Persona persona = new Persona(editTextNombre.getText().toString(),
                    editTextFecha.getText().toString(), editTextZodiaco
                    .getText().toString(), ruta_imagen);

            // Se inserta una nueva persona.
            personaId = baseDatos.insertarPersona(persona);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mensaje.mostrarMensajeCorto("Error, por favor empieza de nuevo");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // Se cierra la base de datos.
            baseDatos.cerrar();
        }
        return personaId;
    }

    /**
     * Metodo privado que edita una persona existente.
     */
    private void editarPersona() {
        baseDatos = new DatabaseHandler(EditarPersonaActivity.this);

        try {
            // Crear objeto persona.
            int id = extras.getInt("id");

            Persona persona = new Persona(id, editTextNombre.getText()
                    .toString(), editTextFecha.getText().toString(),
                    editTextZodiaco.getText().toString(), ruta_imagen);

            baseDatos.actualizarRegistros(id, persona.getNombre(),
                    persona.getFecha(), persona.getZodiaco(),
                    persona.getRutaImagen());
            setAlarm(uriAlarm, id);
            mensaje.mostrarMensajeCorto("Se edito correctamente");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mensaje.mostrarMensajeCorto("Error al querer editarlo, por favor intentelo de nuevo");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            baseDatos.cerrar();
        }
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public boolean estadoEditarPersona() {
        // Si extras es diferente a null es porque tiene valores. En este caso
        // es porque se quiere editar una persona.
        if (extras != null) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }


    private void setAlarm(Uri passuri, int notification_id) throws ParseException {

        System.currentTimeMillis();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
        java.util.Calendar cal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(sdf.parse(editTextFecha.getText().toString()));
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), otrointento.dos.notif.AlarmReceiver.class);
        //los extras
        intent.putExtra("titulo", editTextNombre.getText().toString());
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                getBaseContext(),
                notification_id,
                intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);

                // Cerrar EditarPersonaActivity.
                EditarPersonaActivity.this.finish();

                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        // Coloco todos los objetos en null.
        imagenPersona = null;

        // LLama al recolector de basura.
        System.gc();

    }
}
```

DataBaseHandler

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    // Ruta por defecto de las bases de datos en el sistema Android.
    private static String RUTA_BASE_DATOS = "/data/data/otrointento.dos/databases/";

    // Nombre de la Base de Datos.
    private static String NOMBRE_BASE_DATOS = "BDBIRTHDAY_INFO";

    // Version de la Base de Datos.
    private static final int VERSION_BASE_DATOS = 1;

    // Objeto Base de Datos.
    private SQLiteDatabase base_datos;

    // Objeto Contexto.
    private Context contexto;

    // Constante privada
    private String SENTENCIA_SQL_CREAR_BASE_DATOS_PERSONAS = "CREATE TABLE if not exists personas (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement, " +
            "nombre TEXT, fecha TEXT, zodiaco TEXT, ruta_imagen TEXT)";

    /**
     * Constructor
     * Toma referencia hacia el contexto de la aplicación que lo invoca para poder acceder a los 'assets' y
     * 'resources' de la aplicación.
     * Crea un objeto DBOpenHelper que nos permitirá controlar la apertura de la base de datos.
     * @param context
     */
    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, NOMBRE_BASE_DATOS, null, VERSION_BASE_DATOS);
        this.contexto = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // Se ejecuta la sentencia SQL de creación de la tabla personas.
        db.execSQL(SENTENCIA_SQL_CREAR_BASE_DATOS_PERSONAS);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Se elimina la versión anterior de la tabla Personas.
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Personas");

        // Se crea la nueva versión de la tabla personas.
        db.execSQL(SENTENCIA_SQL_CREAR_BASE_DATOS_PERSONAS);
    }

    /**
     * Metodo publico para insertar una nueva persona.
     */
    public long insertarPersona(Persona persona){
        ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
        valores.put("nombre", persona.getNombre());
        valores.put("fecha", persona.getFecha());
        valores.put("zodiaco", persona.getZodiaco());
        valores.put("ruta_imagen", persona.getRutaImagen());
        return this.getWritableDatabase().insert("Personas", null, valores);
    }

    /**
     * Metodo publico para actualizar una persona.
     */
    public void actualizarRegistros(int id, String nombre, String fecha, String zodiaco, String ruta_imagen){
        ContentValues actualizarDatos = new ContentValues();
        actualizarDatos.put("nombre", nombre);
        actualizarDatos.put("fecha", fecha);
        actualizarDatos.put("zodiaco", zodiaco);
        actualizarDatos.put("ruta_imagen", ruta_imagen);
        String where = "_id=?";
        String[] whereArgs = new String[] {String.valueOf(id)};

        try{
            this.getReadableDatabase().update("Personas", actualizarDatos, where, whereArgs);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            String error =  e.getMessage().toString();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Metodo publico que retorna una persona especifica.
     * @param id
     * @return
     */
    public Persona getPersona(int p_id) {
        String[] columnas = new String[]{"_id", "nombre", "fecha", "zodiaco", "ruta_imagen"};
        Cursor cursor = this.getReadableDatabase().query("Personas", columnas, "_id" + "= " + p_id, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null){
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }

        Persona persona = new Persona(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3),
                cursor.getString(4));

        // Retorna la persona especifica.
        return persona;
    }

    /**
     * Metodo publico que cierra la base de datos.
     */
    public void cerrar(){
        this.close();
    }

    /**
     * Metodo publico que devuelve todas las personas.
     * @return
     */
    public Cursor obtenerTodasPersonas(){
        String[] columnas = new String[]{"_id", "nombre", "fecha", "zodiaco", "ruta_imagen"};
        Cursor cursor = this.getReadableDatabase().query("Personas", columnas, null, null, null, null, null);

        if(cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return cursor;
    }


    /**
     * Metodo publico que elimina una persona especifica.
     * @param rowId
     * @return
     */
    public boolean eliminaPersona(long id){
        return this.getWritableDatabase().delete("Personas", "_id" + "=" + id, null) > 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Dónde asignas la variable `notification_id`?

Comment: En EditarPersonaActivity y en AlarmReceiver, así private int notification_id; , he añadido a la pregunta las dos clases para que puedas verlo mejor y por necesitas algún dato más para ayudarme a encontrar la solución, GRACIAS @dan_flo10 !

Comment: Puedes agregar la clase `DatabaseHandler`

Comment: Añadido a la pregunta @dan_flo10 gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es la variable `notification_id` debe de ser el id que guardas en la base de datos. La respuesta no es la mejor ya que no deberías tener campos y parámetros con los mismos nombres, incluso hay variables sin usar, pero con lo siguiente ya debe de funcionar. Estudia mucho java, solo, sin android, saludos.

Cambia

```
public long insertarPersona(Persona persona){
    ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
    valores.put("nombre", persona.getNombre());
    valores.put("fecha", persona.getFecha());
    valores.put("zodiaco", persona.getZodiaco());
    valores.put("ruta_imagen", persona.getRutaImagen());
    return this.getWritableDatabase().insert("Personas", null, valores);
}

private long insertarNuevoPersona() {
    long personaId = -1;
    baseDatos = new DatabaseHandler(EditarPersonaActivity.this);

    try {
        // Crear objeto Persona.
        Persona persona = new Persona(editTextNombre.getText().toString(),
                editTextFecha.getText().toString(), editTextZodiaco
                .getText().toString(), ruta_imagen);

        // Se inserta una nueva persona.
        personaId = baseDatos.insertarPersona(persona);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        mensaje.mostrarMensajeCorto("Error, por favor empieza de nuevo");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        // Se cierra la base de datos.
        baseDatos.cerrar();
    }
    return personaId;
}


butonGuardar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (verificarCampoNombre() && verificarCampoFecha()
                    && verificarCampoZodiaco()) {
                if (estadoEditarPersona()) {
                    editarPersona();
                } else {
                    try {
                        notification_id = (int)insertarNuevoPersona();
                        setAlarm(uriAlarm, notification_id);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
                // Finaliza la actividad EditarPersonaActivity.
                finish();
            } else {
                if (editTextNombre.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    mensaje.mostrarMensajeCorto("Introduzca un Nombre");
                }
                if (editTextFecha.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    mensaje.mostrarMensajeCorto("Introduzca una Fecha");
                }
                if (editTextZodiaco.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    mensaje.mostrarMensajeCorto("Introduzca su Zodiaco");
                }
            }
        }
    });

private void editarPersona() {
    baseDatos = new DatabaseHandler(EditarPersonaActivity.this);

    try {
        // Crear objeto persona.
        int id = extras.getInt("id");

        Persona persona = new Persona(id, editTextNombre.getText()
                .toString(), editTextFecha.getText().toString(),
                editTextZodiaco.getText().toString(), ruta_imagen);

        baseDatos.actualizarRegistros(id, persona.getNombre(),
                persona.getFecha(), persona.getZodiaco(),
                persona.getRutaImagen());
        setAlarm(uriAlarm, id);
        mensaje.mostrarMensajeCorto("Se edito correctamente");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        mensaje.mostrarMensajeCorto("Error al querer editarlo, por favor intentelo de nuevo");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        baseDatos.cerrar();
    }
}
```

Y además quita de esta línea del Receiver y de la Activity `notification_id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();`

Comment: Lo primero gracias por tu ayuda, me ha funcionado a la perfección! Intento aprender lo máximo posible y vosotros me ayudáis mucho! Pero me queda mucho como bien comentas! Las variables sin usar es porque estoy limpiando el código ya que hice muchas pruebas y borre ahora estoy ordenándolo todo mejor! Para no abrir otra pregunta he añadido a la pregunta lo único que sigue fallando del código y es que no puedo borrar las alarmas, ya funciona correctamente el editarlas pero no el borrarlas, por mucho que la borre siguen sonando, ojalá me puedas ayudar! Gracias por todo @dan_flo10

Comment: Sí elabora otra pregunta, ya que es otro tema, en ella agrega la clase `ImagenAdapter`

Comment: Gracias @dan_flo10 ! marco somo solucionado aquí y abro una nueva pregunta para el problema de Borrar las Alarmas, te lo dejo aquí por si puedes pasarte, gracias ! http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/44723/problemas-al-borrar-alarma