# Problemas al Borrar Alarma

Tags: java, android

Tengo un problema con mis Alarmas, puedo añadirlas y modificarlas, pero **no** borrarlas.
Creo una *persona* con imagen, nombre y alarma, a la hora de borrarla solamente se borra la imagen y nombre la alarma siempre se queda activada

Para borrar la persona lo hago así (borra imagen y nombre, pero **NO** la alarma)

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_contextual_editar_persona:
            editarPersona((int)info.id);
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_contextual_eliminar_persona:
            eliminarPersona((int)info.id);
            recuperarTodasPersonas();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected((android.view.MenuItem) item);
    }
}
```

Dejo aquí mi `MainActivity` completo por si hace falta algún dato más:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Objetos.
    private DatabaseHandler baseDatos;
    private ImagenAdapter cursorAdapter;
    private ListView listViewPersonas;


    // Constantes privadas.
    private int CODIGO_RESULT_EDITAR_PERSONA = 0;
    private static final String SAMPLE_DB_NAME = "BDBIRTHDAY_INFO";
    private static final String SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME = "Personas";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listViewPersonas = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewPersonas);
        // Se recuperan todas las personas de la base de datos.
        recuperarTodasPersonas();
        // Asociamos los menús contextuales al listViewPersonas.
        registerForContextMenu(listViewPersonas);
    }
    /**
     * Metodo publico que se sobreescribe. En este metodo crearmos el menu contextual
     * para el ListView de personas.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo){
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        android.view.MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.opciones_personas, menu);
    }

    /**
     * Metodo publico que se sobreescribe. En este metodo colocamos las acciones de las opciones del menu contextual
     * para el ListView de personas.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem item) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_contextual_editar_persona:
                editarPersona((int)info.id);
                return true;
            case R.id.menu_contextual_eliminar_persona:
                eliminarPersona((int)info.id);
                recuperarTodasPersonas();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onContextItemSelected((android.view.MenuItem) item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();;
    }

    /**
     * Metodo privado que recupera todos las personas existentes de la base de datos.
     */
    private void recuperarTodasPersonas() {
        try{
            baseDatos = new DatabaseHandler(this);

            // Devuelve todas las personas en el objeto Cursor.
            Cursor cursor = baseDatos.obtenerTodasPersonas();

            String[] from = new String[]{
                    "nombre",
                    "fecha",
                    "zodiaco",
                    "ruta_imagen"
            };

            int[] to = new int[]{
                    R.id.persona_nombre,
                    R.id.persona_fecha,
                    R.id.persona_zodiaco,
                    R.id.foto_gallery,
            };
            cursorAdapter = new ImagenAdapter(this, cursor, from, to);
            listViewPersonas.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Error", "El mensaje de error es: " + e.getMessage());
        }finally{
            // Se cierra la base de datos.
            baseDatos.cerrar();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Metodo publico que edita una persona.
     * @param p_id
     */
    public void editarPersona(int p_id){
        // Si el p_id es 0, entonces se crea una nueva persona.
        if(p_id == 0){
            // Se dirige a la actividad EditarPersonaActivity.
            Intent actividad_editarPersona = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditarPersonaActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(actividad_editarPersona, CODIGO_RESULT_EDITAR_PERSONA);
        }else{
            // Recupera una persona especifica.
            Persona persona;

            try{
                persona = baseDatos.getPersona(p_id);

                // Se dirige a la actividad EditarPersonaActivity.
                Intent actividad_editarPersona = new Intent(this, EditarPersonaActivity.class);

                // Se le coloca parametros para enviar a la actividad EditarPersonaActivity.
                actividad_editarPersona.putExtra("id", p_id);
                actividad_editarPersona.putExtra("nombre", persona.getNombre());
                actividad_editarPersona.putExtra("fecha", persona.getFecha());
                actividad_editarPersona.putExtra("zodiaco", persona.getZodiaco());
                actividad_editarPersona.putExtra("ruta_imagen", persona.getRutaImagen());

                startActivityForResult(actividad_editarPersona, CODIGO_RESULT_EDITAR_PERSONA);
            }catch (Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error al editar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                baseDatos.cerrar();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Metodo privado que elimina una persona.
     * @param id_persona
     */
    private void eliminarPersona(int id_persona){
        // Objetos.
        AlertDialog.Builder mensaje_dialogo = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        // Variables.
        final int v_id_persona = id_persona;

        mensaje_dialogo.setTitle("Importante");
        mensaje_dialogo.setMessage("¿Está seguro de eliminar esta persona?");
        mensaje_dialogo.setCancelable(false);
        mensaje_dialogo.setPositiveButton("Confirmar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogo1, int id) {
                try{
                    baseDatos.eliminaPersona(v_id_persona);

                    recuperarTodasPersonas();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error al eliminar!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally{
                    baseDatos.cerrar();
                }
            }
        });
        mensaje_dialogo.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogo1, int id) {
                recuperarTodasPersonas();
            }
        });
        mensaje_dialogo.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        recuperarTodasPersonas();
    }
}
```

`EditarPersona` (solamente parte del código)

Así funciona mi Alarma para activarse:

```
    private void setAlarm(Uri passuri, int notification_id) throws ParseException {

        System.currentTimeMillis();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
        java.util.Calendar cal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(sdf.parse(editTextFecha.getText().toString()));
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), otrointento.dos.notif.AlarmReceiver.class);
        //los extras
        intent.putExtra("titulo", editTextNombre.getText().toString());
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                getBaseContext(),
                notification_id,
                intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

    }


//// luego pulsando mi botón se añade

        butonGuardar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (verificarCampoNombre() && verificarCampoFecha()
                        && verificarCampoZodiaco()) {
                    if (estadoEditarPersona()) {
                        editarPersona();
                    } else {
                        try {
                            notification_id = (int) insertarNuevoPersona();
                            setAlarm(uriAlarm, notification_id);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                    finish();

                }
```

`DataBaseHandler`

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    // Ruta por defecto de las bases de datos en el sistema Android.
    private static String RUTA_BASE_DATOS = "/data/data/otrointento.dos/databases/";

    // Nombre de la Base de Datos.
    private static String NOMBRE_BASE_DATOS = "BDBIRTHDAY_INFO";

    // Version de la Base de Datos.
    private static final int VERSION_BASE_DATOS = 1;

    // Objeto Base de Datos.
    private SQLiteDatabase base_datos;

    // Objeto Contexto.
    private Context contexto;

    // Constante privada
    private String SENTENCIA_SQL_CREAR_BASE_DATOS_PERSONAS = "CREATE TABLE if not exists personas (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement, " +
            "nombre TEXT, fecha TEXT, zodiaco TEXT, ruta_imagen TEXT)";

    /**
     * Constructor
     * Toma referencia hacia el contexto de la aplicación que lo invoca para poder acceder a los 'assets' y
     * 'resources' de la aplicación.
     * Crea un objeto DBOpenHelper que nos permitirá controlar la apertura de la base de datos.
     * @param context
     */
    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, NOMBRE_BASE_DATOS, null, VERSION_BASE_DATOS);
        this.contexto = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // Se ejecuta la sentencia SQL de creación de la tabla personas.
        db.execSQL(SENTENCIA_SQL_CREAR_BASE_DATOS_PERSONAS);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Se elimina la versión anterior de la tabla Personas.
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Personas");

        // Se crea la nueva versión de la tabla personas.
        db.execSQL(SENTENCIA_SQL_CREAR_BASE_DATOS_PERSONAS);
    }

    /**
     * Metodo publico para insertar una nueva persona.
     */
    public long insertarPersona(Persona persona){
        ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
        valores.put("nombre", persona.getNombre());
        valores.put("fecha", persona.getFecha());
        valores.put("zodiaco", persona.getZodiaco());
        valores.put("ruta_imagen", persona.getRutaImagen());
        return this.getWritableDatabase().insert("Personas", null, valores);
    }

    /**
     * Metodo publico para actualizar una persona.
     */
    public void actualizarRegistros(int id, String nombre, String fecha, String zodiaco, String ruta_imagen){
        ContentValues actualizarDatos = new ContentValues();
        actualizarDatos.put("nombre", nombre);
        actualizarDatos.put("fecha", fecha);
        actualizarDatos.put("zodiaco", zodiaco);
        actualizarDatos.put("ruta_imagen", ruta_imagen);
        String where = "_id=?";
        String[] whereArgs = new String[] {String.valueOf(id)};

        try{
            this.getReadableDatabase().update("Personas", actualizarDatos, where, whereArgs);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            String error =  e.getMessage().toString();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Metodo publico que retorna una persona especifica.
     * @param id
     * @return
     */
    public Persona getPersona(int p_id) {
        String[] columnas = new String[]{"_id", "nombre", "fecha", "zodiaco", "ruta_imagen"};
        Cursor cursor = this.getReadableDatabase().query("Personas", columnas, "_id" + "= " + p_id, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null){
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }

        Persona persona = new Persona(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3),
                cursor.getString(4));

        // Retorna la persona especifica.
        return persona;
    }

    /**
     * Metodo publico que cierra la base de datos.
     */
    public void cerrar(){
        this.close();
    }

    /**
     * Metodo publico que devuelve todas las personas.
     * @return
     */
    public Cursor obtenerTodasPersonas(){
        String[] columnas = new String[]{"_id", "nombre", "fecha", "zodiaco", "ruta_imagen"};
        Cursor cursor = this.getReadableDatabase().query("Personas", columnas, null, null, null, null, null);

        if(cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return cursor;
    }


    /**
     * Metodo publico que elimina una persona especifica.
     * @param rowId
     * @return
     */
    public boolean eliminaPersona(long id){
        return this.getWritableDatabase().delete("Personas", "_id" + "=" + id, null) > 0;
    }
}
```

`ImagenAdapter`:

```
public class ImagenAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
    // Objetos de clase.
    private Cursor cursor;
    private Context contexto;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;


    static class ViewHolder{
        TextView textViewNombre;
        TextView textViewFecha;
        TextView textViewZodiaco;
        ImageView thumb_persona;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor con 4 parametros.
     * @param contexto
     * @param cursor
     * @param from
     * @param to
     */
    public ImagenAdapter(Context contexto, Cursor cursor, String[] from,
                         int[] to) {
        super(contexto, R.layout.fila_persona, cursor, from, to);
        this.contexto = contexto;
        this.cursor = cursor;
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(contexto);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null){
            convertView = this.mInflater.inflate(R.layout.fila_persona, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.textViewNombre = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.persona_nombre);
            viewHolder.textViewFecha = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.persona_fecha);
            viewHolder.textViewZodiaco = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.persona_zodiaco);
            viewHolder.thumb_persona = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.foto_gallery);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }else{
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        this.cursor.moveToPosition(position);

        viewHolder.textViewNombre.setText(this.cursor.getString(this.cursor.getColumnIndex("nombre")));
        viewHolder.textViewFecha.setText(this.cursor.getString(this.cursor.getColumnIndex("fecha")));
        viewHolder.textViewZodiaco.setText(this.cursor.getString(this.cursor.getColumnIndex("zodiaco")));

        // Se obtiene la ruta de la imagen.
        String ruta_imagen = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ruta_imagen"));

        File imagenArchivo = new  File(ruta_imagen);
        if(imagenArchivo.exists()){
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagenArchivo.getAbsolutePath());
            BitmapFactory.Options opciones = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            opciones.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(ruta_imagen, opciones);

            int scaleW = opciones.outWidth / 854 + 1;
            int scaleH = opciones.outHeight / 480 + 1;
            int scale = Math.max(scaleW, scaleH);

            opciones.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            opciones.inSampleSize = scale;
            opciones.inSampleSize = scale;
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(ruta_imagen, opciones);
            viewHolder.thumb_persona.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**Edito:**

`Log`

```
// cuando guardo la DB

02-20 14:15:32.473 24882-24882/vrteam.birthday I/MainActivity: inicia exportDB()
02-20 14:15:32.479 24882-24882/vrteam.birthday I/MainActivity: es directorio: /storage/emulated/0/BirthdayBackup
02-20 14:15:32.485 24882-24882/vrteam.birthday I/MainActivity: termina exportDB()...


// cuando restauro la DB

02-20 14:16:39.888 24882-25168/vrteam.birthday I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
02-20 14:16:39.888 24882-25168/vrteam.birthday D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
02-20 14:16:43.311 24882-24882/vrteam.birthday E/MainActivity: inicia importDB()
02-20 14:16:43.340 24882-24882/vrteam.birthday E/MainActivity: Termina importDB() procede a activar alertas.
02-20 14:16:43.344 24882-24882/vrteam.birthday I/MainActivity: Activando alarma 1 para usuario Uno
02-20 14:16:43.345 24882-24882/vrteam.birthday I/MainActivity:  alarma 20/2/2017 14:18
```

Comment: Hola, creo que el codigo que aportas es mucho. Crees que **todo** está implicado en tu problema y es relevante para su resolucion?

Comment: Sí, vengo de otra pregunta para Editar las Alarmas e hizo falta todo lo que añado, gracias @lois6b

Comment: Ok , siendo asi callo :/ ^^'

Comment: Sí puedes editar la persona?

Comment: según yo es por una coincidencia, pero ya te respondí

Comment: En mi comentario anterior me refiero que no puedo eliminar las Alarmas, la persona sí (imagen, nombre...) pero la Alarma no se cancela @dan_flo10

Comment: He editado mi pregunta y añadido una recompensa, creo que no hace falta más información para ayudarme a solucionar mi pregunta, y creo que tampoco es demasiado código el que incluyo, es el que me han pedido para intentar solucionar mi problema

Comment: realmente usted agrega la alarma con AlarmManager alarmManager,del mismo modo debe acudir a ella para cancelar la alarma. alarmManager.cancel(pending_intent) https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: Mis alarmas usan una `id` que auto incrementa, no puedo cancelar todas las alarmas, solamente de la persona que borre y la alarma la creo en mi clase `EditarPersona` @Maguz

Comment: @UserNameYo revisa mi respuesta, es importante tener el id con el que generaste el pendingIntent para que identifique el AlarmManager que alarma debe cancelar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para cancelar la Alarma es relativamente sencillo, toma de base el PendingIntent que creaste:

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), otrointento.dos.notif.AlarmReceiver.class);
    //los extras
    intent.putExtra("titulo", editTextNombre.getText().toString());
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            getBaseContext(),
            notification_id,
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Mediante el [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) puedes cancelar tu alarma que previamente configuraste, es importante tener el id del `requestCode` con el cual se genero el `Intent` (en tu caso es `notification_id`) para de esta forma identificar cual es la Alarma configurada que se desea cancelar, el método usado para cancerla es [cancel()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#cancel(android.app.PendingIntent))  :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), otrointento.dos.notif.AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), notification_id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
//Cancela Alarma.
alarmManager.cancel(sender);
```

Con esto será suficiente para cancelar tu alarma.

---

> [AlarmManager.cancel()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#cancel(android.app.PendingIntent)) Elimina las alarmas con un Intent
>   coincidente. Cualquier alarma, de cualquier tipo, cuyo Intent coincida
>   con este, será cancelado.

---

**La ùnica forma de asegurar cancelar la Alarma es mediante el id con el que fue creada.**

**Análisis del código:** Para cancelar la alerta al eliminar el usuario puedes usar un método el cual cancela la alarma mediante su id, el código sería:

```
  @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem item) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_contextual_editar_persona:
                editarPersona((int)info.id);
                return true;
            case R.id.menu_contextual_eliminar_persona:
                eliminaAlerta((int)info.id); /** CANCELA ALARMA**/
                eliminarPersona((int)info.id);
                recuperarTodasPersonas();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onContextItemSelected((android.view.MenuItem) item);
        }
    }

    public void eliminaAlerta(int id){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), vrteam.birthday.notif.AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        //Cancela Alarma.
        alarmManager.cancel(sender); 
    }
```

Existe un detalle a corregir el cual al parecer podría no permitir registrar la alarma, dentro de la clase `EditarPersonaActivity` método `setAlarm()`, el formato que usas no es el mismo que el usado al definir el `SimpleDateFormat()`, al generar un error no podría registrar la Alarma, por lo tanto realiza este cambio:

```
  //  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
```

Comment: añadir  alarmMaganer.cancel(sender);  pero con el PendingIntent creado con el mismo id con el que generaste la Alarma. De hecho no veo donde trataste de eliminar la Alarma, indicame en tu código en que punto deseas realizar este procedimiento y te ayudo. @UserNameYo

Comment: Agregué una actualización, podrías agregar el método insertarNuevoPersona() para revisarlo. Tendrás tu proyecto completo en Github? podría revisarlo por completo.

Comment: @UserNameYo, si, el día de ayer en la noche dí un vistazo, revisa la actualización, no debes tener problemas, me comentas resultados, saludos.

Comment: Ya puedo desactivar, por fin! todas las alarmas, muchísimas gracias @Jorgesys gracias por tu ayuda de verdad! Ahora tengo un problema, que hago un backup de mi `sqlite` y al restaurarlo las Alarmas que tenía no están activada, cómo podría solucionarlo? Te lo pregunto aquí y no en otra pregunta porque como ya has visto mi código completo seguramente sepas solucionarlo y puedas ayudarme. Nuevamente muchísimas gracias por ayudarme @Jorgesys por cierto lo que me has comentado de `setAlarm()` no he realizado ese cambio porque entonces no puedo configurar la hora para que suene la alarma

Comment: Que bien, de hecho tenias correcto el código solo faltaba agregar la cancelación con el mismo id que tenias en la BD. Necesito más detalles, como restauras la base de datos?

Comment: @UserNameYo hey si lo ví ayer pero los dos botones tienen un listener pero no tienen una tarea a realizar, cuales son los métodos para backup/restore?

Comment: Te he dado ya los +100 porque me ayudaste a solucionar mi pregunta y caduca en 16h y no quiero que se pase, porque te los mereces, cuando puedas me dices si pudiste ver porque al restaurar los backup las alarmas no están activadas. Gracias @Jorgesys

Comment: @UserNameYo , hola estoy instalando todo el software a una Mac, por cierto en este momento el SDK platform 25 que tiene tu proyecto, por cierto  podrìa subir directamente a tu repositorio código con respecto a esto? me imagino es solo de prueba.

Comment: @UserNameYo si, de hecho el problema como comentabamos era que no estaba guardando la hora! lo subo más tarde.

Comment: Has podido subirlo? Gracias !! @Jorgesys

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54308/android-userone

Answer (score 1):

Como no sé hasta donde avanzaste en tu código por mientras con las otras problemas, te dejo una solución un poco más abstracta.

Para mantener tu código un poco más ordenado, te recomiendo de manejar todo el tema de tus alarmas en tu actividad principal.

Primero te defines constantes:

```
static final int SIN_CAMBIO=0;
static final int NUEVO_USUARIO;
static final int USUARIO_EDITADO;
static final int USUARIO_BORRADO;
```

En vez de usar `setResult(int codigo)` en las actividades para crear/editar usuarios, usas:

```
setResult(SIN_CAMBIO, intent); // si no cambió nada o el resultado fue cancelado (onBackButton)
setResult(NUEVO_USUARIO, intent); // con los nuevos datos del usuario en el intent
setResult(USUARIO_EDITADO, intent); // idem
setResult(USUARIO_BORADO, intent); // en el caso que usas un intent para borrar
```

Si no usas una actividad para borrar, puedes llamar a `onActivityResult(..)` directo con el resultado y el intent.

Luego dejas todo el código para prender, actualizar y cancelar alarmas en `onActivityResult`:

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        switch(requestCode){
            case SIN_CAMBIO:
                // nada que hacer
                break;
            case NUEVO_USUARIO:
            case USUARIO_EDITADO:
                // obtiene id y fecha de intent (tu código), luego
                setAlarma(uriAlarm, id, fecha);
                break;
            case USUARIO_BORRADO:
                // obtiene id de intent (tu código), luego
                cancelAlarma(uriAlarm, id);
                break;
        }
        recuperarTodasPersonas();
    }
```

Y los métodos para gestionar alarmas:

```
private void setAlarm(Uri passuri, int notification_id, String fecha) throws ParseException {

    System.currentTimeMillis();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
    java.util.Calendar cal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(sdf.parse(fecha));
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), otrointento.dos.notif.AlarmReceiver.class);
    //los extras
    intent.putExtra("titulo", editTextNombre.getText().toString());
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            getBaseContext(),
            notification_id,
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

}
```

cancelar:

```
private void cancelAlarm(Uri passuri, int notification_id){

    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), otrointento.dos.notif.AlarmReceiver.class);
    //los extras no importan
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            getBaseContext(),
            notification_id,
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
}
```

Así tienes todo bien organizado y no distribuido en varios clases.